# Not sure how to set up a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, ios6

I created a DetailViewController .h and .m files. Then I created a UITableViewController in the storyboard and connected it to the files I made.

Then I added this code to the DetailViewController.m file:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

// 1
#import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

// 2
@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSArray *_products;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

// 3
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"In App Rage";

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self reload];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

}

// 4
- (void)reload {
    _products = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// 5
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

But I get compile errors on lines like this:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
```

Saying that self.refreshControl is not recognized. But how can that be if the file is a UITableView file?

EDIT:

This is the .h

```
//
//  DetailViewController.h
//  entrepreneur
//
//  Created by MacOSLion on 8/7/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 MacOSLion. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

Comment: Can you show me the .h file please?

Comment: refreshControl is a property on the UITableViewController class.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique I just added the .h to the original question - thank you

Comment: @onnoweb yes, and in my .h file I declared that. That wasn't enough?

Comment: What is the actual error message? Don't paraphrase, copy and paste the original.

Comment: hi, the example you have given above for the .m file if of MasterViewController and you have mentioned that you have added the code in "DetailViewController.m" file. So please make sure that what exactly it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a mistake somewhere...

See, you show us the implementation of :

```
@implementation MasterViewController
```

But the definition of :

```
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController
```

That's why, of course, it can't find refreshControl in MasterViewController : it is a property of UITableViewController, so of your DetailViewController.

Please tell me if it's not clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .h

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
```

Comment: It gives a warning saying that this property does not match the property inherited from UITableViewController

Comment: This is incorrect. A UITableViewController already has this property, you don't want to declare it again.

Comment: @Genadinik Are you using a UITableViewController or a UIViewController?